# Nginx proxy pass and url rewriting

Tags: nginx

How to trig this rule only when I have parameters in url,
otherwise I will match on an alias.

```
location ~^/static/photos/.* {
    rewrite ^/static/photos/(.*)$  /DynamicPhotoQualitySwitch/photos/$1  break;
    expires     7d;
    proxy_pass http://foofoofoo.com;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
     }
```

Comment: For URL-routing/rewriting questions, it really helps to provide concrete examples of URLs along with descriptions of how you want them handled.

Comment: ... especially if you're willing to give away half of your rep for a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a condition to check if the [$args](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24args) parameter is not empty:

```
location ~^/static/photos/.* {
  if ($args != ''){
    rewrite ^/static/photos/(.*)$  /DynamicPhotoQualitySwitch/photos/$1  break;
    expires     7d;
    proxy_pass http://foofoofoo.com;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
  }  
}
```

Comment: sounds good I will test it asap

Comment: location can not be included in if condition

Comment: This is untested too, but try moving the if condition inside of location, as I edited above.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `*` (meaning 0 or more) to a `+` (meaning 1 or more)

For example, this:

```
location ~^/static/photos/.* {
    rewrite ^/static/photos/(.*)$  /DynamicPhotoQualitySwitch/photos/$1  break;
    expires     7d;
    proxy_pass http://foofoofoo.com;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
}
```

becomes:

```
location ~^/static/photos/.+ {
    rewrite ^/static/photos/(.+)$  /DynamicPhotoQualitySwitch/photos/$1  break;
    expires     7d;
    proxy_pass http://foofoofoo.com;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
}
```

Comment: arguments(query string) are not present in "location", so it will not work, my question are not about regex. but thank you

Comment: You're right. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer now that I understand the question better:

Have you tried [try_files](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files)?

For example it would probably look something like:

```
try_files /DynamicPhotoQualitySwitch/photos/$args /path/for/no/args;

location /path/for/no/args {
    expires     7d;
    proxy_pass http://foofoofoo.com;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
}
```